# Compare tokens with strcmp

Tags: c, arrays, string

I need to compare tokens.
I need to know two tokens which are equal.
This is my code. And something is going wrong when comparing- compilator just crashes. 
Can you help me to find error?

```
int main()    
{
    int i=0;
    char* words[200];
    char text[200];

    printf("Enter one sentence \n ");
    gets(text);
    char *word = strtok(text, " ");

    while(word!=0)
    {
        words[i++] = strdup(word);
        printf("[%s]\n", word);
        word=strtok(NULL, " ,.!?");
    }






for (k=0; k<199; k++)
{
 for (j=k+1; j<200; j++)
  { 
             if (strcmp(words[k],words[j])==0) 
             {
             printf("Equal words are %s",words);
             }
             else
             {
             printf("In this sentence aren't equal words");
             }
   }

} 
  getch();
        return 0;
```

Comment: "something is going wrong when comparing". Then I guess you need to fix "something". If you want help on the internet, please provide meaningful information for us. For example the intended behaviour and the actual behaviour, so we can help you.

Comment: More specifics on what test sentence was used and what the output of `printf("[%s]\n", word);` produced would be helpful.

Comment: "*compilator just crashes*" -- Do you mean "compiler"? If the compiler crashed, you wouldn't be able to run your program at all.

Comment: Once you fix the other problems, you'll want to avoid using `gets`. Using `gets` to read into a 200-character array won't cause any immediate problems as long as the input isn't too long, but `gets` cannot be used safely, and has been removed from the language. `fgets` is a little trickier to use, but it can be used safely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In your for loops you iterate until 200, not until the max number of entered words (**i**) is reached.
2. There is no guarantee which value the elements of an uninitialized array will have at runtime. They might be 0, but also might be any other random numbers. Which means, that doing strcmp with any array element beyond the number of entered words will result in undefined behavior.

Do your nested for-loop like this:

```
for (k=0; k < i-1; k++)
{
  for (j=k+1; j < i; j++)
  { 
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: for (k=0; k<words[i]-1; k++)
 for (j=k+1; j<words[i]; j++)
But if i try like this then error is
ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question, but I found @elgonzo's answer helpful and was able to get your program to compile after a few other changes. I added the libraries, added `\n` to the print statements, and initialized the variables `k` and `j` which may have been part of your problem.

Here's my version:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main()
    {
        int i=0, k=0, j=0;
        char* words[200];
        char text[200];

        printf("Enter one sentence \n ");
        gets(text);
        char *word = strtok(text, " ");

        while(word!=0)
        {
            words[i++] = strdup(word);
            printf("[%s]\n", word);
            word=strtok(NULL, " ,.!?");
        }

        for (k=0; k < i-1; k++)
        {
         for (j=k+1; j < i; j++)
          {
              if (strcmp(words[k],words[j])==0)
              {
              printf("Equal words are %s\n", *words);
              }
              else
              {
              printf("In this sentence aren't equal words\n");
              }
          }
        }
    return 0;
    }
```